# How to create detached CMS signature?

Tags: openssl

I've been trying to create a detached PKCS#7/CMS signature with OpenSSL.  I have a large zip file which I would like to create a digital signature for, but I don't want the contents embedded in the signature.  Is this possible with OpenSSL, or can it only verify detached signatures and not create them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can, and it's even the default for [the commandline utility](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/cms.html) -- you must specify `-nodetach` to 'embed' the data. But counterintuitively PKCS#7/CMS format is *not* the default (S/MIME is) so you must specify `-outform`.
Assuming you have the privatekey in one of the several supported PEM formats in `pkey.pem` and the corresponding certificate also in PEM in `cert.pem`, and the data in `data` and you want 'raw' (binary) CMS in `signature`:

```
openssl cms -sign -signer cert.pem -inkey pkey.pem -binary -in data -outform der -out signature
```

If the cert and key are in the same PEM file (a sometimes convenient feature of OpenSSL's slightly extended PEM format) specify that file to `-signer` and omit `-inkey`. If the key and cert are in any non-PEM format(s), including PKCS#12, convert them to PEM first.

For PEM-format output change to `-outform pem`. On an OS/shell supporting redirection (which I think is now all but VMS), omitting `-in` or `-out` uses stdin or stdout respectively, which can include piping from or to other processes. (Of course, it is vital the signed data be reproduced bit-for-bit by the recipient/verifier, and often that's more difficult if it's not in a file.)

By default OpenSSL uses the `signedAttributes` aka two-level aka indirect form of signature; to sign *only* the data (hashed) add `-noattr`. See the manpage for more options: omit the signer cert or include additional (chain) certs for the verifier, change the indicated content-type and signature hash and algorithm options.

If you prefer to write your own program using the (C) API, start at [CMS_sign](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/CMS_sign.html). You should also be able to see these (and related) man pages locally on any Unix system with OpenSSL installed, usually just `man cms` and `man CMS_sign` etc although some installs may require adjusting your MANPATH and/or specifying special sections like 1ssl and 3ssl.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably discuss the API calls. If the OP was interested in the command line utility, he/she would have asked on Super User.

Comment: I actually was asking about the command line utility and not the C API.  But now I know to ask this question in SuperUser instead.  Thanks.

Comment: "But counterintuitively PKCS#7/CMS format is not the default (S/MIME is) so you must specify -outform".  WOW.  Ridiculous.  This was my exact problem.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: The links for the answers are broken. Can you update them please ?